# How to get memory base address of a c# assembly loaded in a different AppDomain

Tags: c#, process, .net-assembly, memory-address, appdomain

You can get the memory base address of the modules loaded on your process with some code like this one below:

```
ProcessModuleCollection pc = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules;
foreach(ProcessModule pm in pc)
{
        Console.WriteLine("The moduleName is " + pm.ModuleName);
        Console.WriteLine("The " + pm.ModuleName + "'s base address is: " + pm.BaseAddress);
}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working with the scenario that I have. What I'm doing is to create a new and separated AppDomain (called Temporal) and using it to load an assembly from disk. Then, I just execute some function contained in the loaded assembly. This would be the code of the class that contains all this logic:

```
    public class Loader : MarshalByRefObject
    {
        object CallInternal(string dll, string method, string[] parameters)
        {
            byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(dll);
            Assembly a = Assembly.Load(buffer);
            Type[] types = a.GetTypes();
            MethodInfo m = null;
            Type myType = null;
            foreach (var type in types)
            {

                m = type.GetMethod(method);
                if (m != null)
                {
                    myType = type;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (m != null && myType != null)
            {
                var myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
                return m.Invoke(myInstance, new object[] { parameters });
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        public static object Call(string dll, string method, params string[] parameters)
        {
            AppDomain dom = AppDomain.CreateDomain("Temporal");
            Loader ld = (Loader)dom.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, typeof(Loader).FullName);
            object result = ld.CallInternal(dll, typename, method, parameters);
            return result;
        }
```

The question is, is there any way to get the memory base address of the loaded assembly without executing some sort of memory scan? The `ProcessModuleCollection` that you get from `Process.GetCurrentProcess().Modules` is not showing the assembly loaded in the AppDomain `Temporal`. Unsafe and unmanaged code allowed.

Comment: What do you intend to use the base address for? What is your actual goal?

Comment: @JonasH I'm trying to figure it out if I can recover the assembly from memory once the AppDomain has been unloaded. Thats why I need the module base address, so I can read the memory content and obtain the code.

Comment: While I cannot find a reference, I would be surprised if the memory for the assembly is valid after the appdomain has unloaded. But you are still not describing the actual goal, if you are after the IL code, why not just read it from file directly?

Comment: @JonasH Im reading it from disk, but in real life you can download an assembly from a remote url and load it directly on memory (therefore, there is not IL code in disk). My main goal is to create a tool that is able detect this memory injections and recover the assembly from memory for further inspection even after ther appdomain has been unloaded. This would be very usefull in cybersecurity, among other IT fields.